# Applying DataTemplates to Sample/Design Data in Expression Blend

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, expression-blend, design-time, design-time-data

I have a ListView that is supposed to display objects of class `Sensor`, for which I created a simple (for now) DataTemplate.

In order to further design this DataTemplate in Expression Blend, I created Sample Data from Class [as shown in the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff724024(v=expression.40).aspx) (although I am using Blend for Visual Studio 2013, but it seems to be the same).

I can successfully get the Sample Data I created being displayed in a ListView, but it is not using the DataTemplate I created, since the elements displayed seem to belong to a different, "design" namespace:

- The qualified name of my class is `Miotec.BioSinais.ModeloDomínio.Sensor`;
- (But) the qualified name of the displayed class is `_.di0.Miotec.BioSinais.ModeloDomínio.Sensor`.

What am I doing wrong? (code and screenshot below)

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:dominio="clr-namespace:Miotec.BioSinais.ModeloDomínio;assembly=Miotec.BioSinais"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="Miotec.ProtótipoColeta.ColetaConfigView"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="ColetaConfigView"
    Width="640" Height="480">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dominio:Sensor}">
            <Border>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nome}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate> 
    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid x:Name="PainelCentral">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <DockPanel x:Name="PainelSetupsSensores" Background="#FFB8E6E8"/>
            <DockPanel x:Name="PainelSensoresDisponiveis" Background="#FFC5E2A8"
                Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" 
                DataContext="{Binding ReceiverAtivo}"
                d:DataContext="{d:DesignData /SampleData/ReceiverSimuladoSampleData.xaml}">
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Sensores}" Margin="10"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

====

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Miotec.BioSinais.ModeloDomínio
{
    public abstract class Sensor : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public abstract string Nome { get; set; }

        public virtual int NívelBateria { get; set; }

        public virtual int NívelSinalWireless { get; set; }

        public virtual EstadoSensor Estado { get; protected set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Canal> Canais { get; protected set; }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged (string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

==============

[image]